# Use jQuery to disable externally linked .js/.css in header?

Tags: jquery, header, comments, out

Is it possible to use jQuery to disable/comment out a header file and then later re-enable it, sort of toggle it on/off disable/enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (for css files):

```
$('link[type="text/css"]').each(function(){
  var $ele = $(this);

  //check if atribute data is set and has info
  if ($ele.attr('data') !== undefined && $ele.attr('data') !== ''){ //set, so adding that info to href attribute and emptying data attribute

    $ele.attr('href', $ele.attr('data'));
    $ele.attr('data', '');

  } else{ //not set/empty, so setting/filling it and emptying href attribute

    $ele.attr('data', $ele.attr('href'));
    $ele.attr('href', '');

  }
});
```

Comment: I think so (never tested), but selector and attribute you need to modify should be different.

Comment: is the attr still data for .js? I have a jquery-toggle.js I am trying to have it enabled by default on page load, which is by default, but I want to click "trigger" and that will disable jquery-toggle.js from the loaded page. Click it again, and jquery-toggle.js will be enabled. I am a bit confused about the .attr data, where should the src="jquery-toggle.js" go in the code above? Thank you for your help egis!

Comment: Sorry, for the late response. Well, attribute "data" is just a placeholder for href value (you don't need to define it in html). If you rewrite code for js then change selector to $('script') and 'href' to 'src'. Bear in mind that it might not work, I can't test it right now :)